Rust installation issue at non-standard path
I have installed rust at non-standard path (I dont have root permission ) by following steps.
Downloaded https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/rust-nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz
cd ~/.rust
tar xvf rust-nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz
mv rust-nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu rust
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.rust/rust/rustc/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=~/.rust/rust/rustc/bin:$PATH
export PATH=~/.rust/rust/cargo/bin:$PATH
 ./install.sh --prefix=~/.rust/
Installation went successful without any error 

export PATH=~/.rust/bin:$PATH

After  that to test the installation I executed following commands
cargo new hello --bin
echo "fn main(){println!(\"Hello World\");}" > hello/src/main.rs
cd hello
cargo build

After this stage i am getting the error
error[E0463]: can't find crate for std
what i have missed here ?
Can anyone please help?

Why does LD_LIBRARY_PATH refer to ~/opt/… instead of ~/.rust/…?

What's ./install.sh?

Ahh ! It's just a typo.. it's actually ~/.rust. ./install.sh is installer came from the downloaded package
